# Hardly making money do I need to pay capital gains tax

Tags: taxes, capital-gains-tax

I'm a college student and I've made around 5k in the past 3 months trading. Do I even need to pay capital gains tax? I don't know anything about taxes

Comment: Add  a tag showing your COUNTRY.

Comment: Assuming you're in the US, it depends on whether your gains are short term (assets held a year or less) or long term.  See here: https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc409

Comment: Is this your only income, or do you also have employment income?

Comment: "I don't know anything about taxes."  You will.  **You will!!!!**

Comment: "I don't know anything about taxes" - well, start learning. FAST. It is your duty to know, the government does not care about ignorance in this regard, and if you think 5000 is small for cap gains - ah, you are going tobe in a world of trouble. LEARN TAX BASICS.

Comment: @RonJohn - heh - good one

Comment: Note - A close doesn't mean the question isn't good, only that it's missing something essential. Please edit, and you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely you have to **FILE** a tax return,

even if you have to **pay nothing**.

That's the most likely situation.

Trading is ALL paperwork. If you have an *"I hate paperwork"* attitude (which is perfectly reasonable), I would strongly suggest just forgetting about trading.

If you're in the US it's extremely easy to file your tax return, using taxact.com or the similar competitive services.

Comment: "forgetting about trading" Or trade in a tax-deferred retirement account so it will sit until you learn to _accept_ paperwork,

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're single, you only **owe**:

- *income* tax if you if you earn more than $12,200 in a year.
- *Social Security* tax on *earned* income; investment income is **un**earned.
- *Medicare* tax if your income is over $200,000.

You **must file** a tax return, but **probably** owe nothing.

(Starting next year, I recommend that you get in the habit of setting aside 10% of unearned income for possible owed taxes.  That way, when you *do* start owing taxes, you'll have kitty for the taxes owed.  It's certainly be less than what you set aside, but That's OK.)

Comment: But if the income is long-term capital gains (assets held more than a year), the tax rate on that income is zero if your income is under $80K or so (IIRC).  Unless it's from something like collectibles...  See the IRS web site.

Comment: @jamesqf: I don't know how tc409 got screwed up, but the LTCG&QD brackets depend on filing status and year. 78,750 was the 0% limit _for MFJ/QW (but not other statuses) in 2019_; the (several) 15% limits stated there were also for 2019. For 2020, since the relevant instructions aren't out yet, see [RP 2019-44 in 2019 IRB 47](https://www.irs.gov/irb/2019-47_IRB#REV-PROC-2019-44) item .03. And note these brackets apply _after_ adjustments and either standard or itemized deductions (although a college student is unlikely to itemize -- unless a foreign/NRA student).